# Rest debugger parameter not working correctly

Tags: delphi, oracle-apex, rad-studio

I use simple oracle apex rest full service, when run test on apex aplication return one row --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtBEI.jpg

When test on Rest debugger in Rad Studio get all rows --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nt7G.jpg

How set parameter and URL in Rest debugger to return one row?

Tnx all.

Comment: I get stuck to this point neearly every time I have to do a Request with parameters that differ just a little bit from the defaults delphi likes to see in this Situation.
My Solution at this Point is, simply use the components you have at this point and build your own testing envoironment.
You have much more possibilitys in jusing tRestclient and tRestrequest Class in your own envoironment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic terms like *parameter* have specific meanings in some contexts. In a URL it means  `?name=value` added to the end of a URL. Be careful not to confuse the generic use of the word with a specific use.

Your web service looks to just put the value in the URL path itself and not as a URL parameter. In the generic sense it is passing a parameter in both cases. Only in the second example below is it passing it as a URL parameter.

```
http://mytestservers.com/hr/employees/5555

http://mytestservers.com/hr/employees?id=5555
```

Parameters can also be passed in the request document in addition to the URL. You need to figure out where parameters need to go.

---

**The help for Oracle APEX** for the example you are working through:

Note also the URI displayed in the browser for this resource:

```
https://server:port/ords/workspace/hr/employees/7369
```

So the ID is just put in the URI not as a URL parameter.